# How to create a loop and move to the cell below when a condition is not met on excel or VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, loops, if-statement

I have a list of keywords and a list of questions on excel. I need to see IF every single keywords is found into the questions or not.

e.g.

```
       A                    B
   1 expense      how is my bonus calculated?
   2 business     how do i change my bank account? 
   3 bonus        how do i apply for a credit card?
```

I was trying to solve it with an IF statement on excel such as:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(A1,B1)),A1,IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(A2,B1)),A2,IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(A3,B1)),A3,"no")))
```

but it works just for few keywords, so I was wondering if there is an alternative way as a formula or maybe an easy method on VBA to create a loop.

In other words: IF A1 is NOT on B1, look at A2, if not, look at A3, etc.

Thanks a lot to everyone will help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

udf formula

```
=isTrue($A$1:$A$3,B1)
```

[image]

**UDF**

```
Function isTrue(rngFind As Range, rngWhat As Range)
    Dim vDB, s As String
    Dim i As Long
    vDB = rngFind
    For i = 1 To UBound(vDB, 1)
        s = vDB(i, 1)
        If InStr(rngWhat, s) Then
            isTrue = s
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next i
    isTrue = "no"
End Function
```

**It is a method to distinguish between uppercase and lowercase letters.**

```
Function isTrue(rngFind As Range, rngWhat As Range)
    Dim vDB, s As String, s2 As String
    Dim i As Long
    vDB = rngFind
    For i = 1 To UBound(vDB, 1)
        s = LCase(vDB(i, 1))
        s2 = LCase(rngWhat)
        If InStr(s2, s) Then
            isTrue = vDB(i, 1)
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next i
    isTrue = "no"
End
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! It works great and the code is very accurate. Thanks a lot Dy. Lee!

Comment: One thing to look out for, is the default string comparison type for Instr is vbBinaryCompare. Meaning these searches in this code will be *case sensitive* so `Bonus` and `bonus` will **not** match. Just FYI. You can change this with the optional Compare parameter in the `InStr` function.

Comment: @Dy.Lee that works. Could've added the vbTextCompare option, or used the string specific LCase$ instead of the variant version. Or `StrComp` would be fast too.

Comment: @RyanWildry, Ok, I knew what you were saying. I learned new things.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this formula.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Texts,MATCH("*" & A1 & "*",Texts,0)),"No found")
```

To make this formula work you should create a named range for your texts. I called it "Texts". You should also write the key word you wish to look up in cell A1 (change as appropriate).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a VBA function if you prefer, tried to make it intuitive.

Call it like: `=ContainsCategory(A1:A3,B1)`

```
Option Explicit

Public Function ContainsCategory(Categories As Excel.Range, Question As Excel.Range) As String
    ContainsCategory = "False"
    Dim Category As Excel.Range

    If Question.Cells.Count > 1 Then
        ContainsCategory = "Question Parameter can only be a single cell"
        Exit Function
    End If

    For Each Category In Categories
        If InStr(1, Question.Value2, Category.Value2, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            ContainsCategory = "True"
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next

End Function
```

Comment: 1,2,3~  values true. 0 is false. So, There is no need for "> 0" in instr ()> 0.

Comment: InStr returns the index where a matching string was located. While it is true you can omit this, I think it is clearer to leave this in. It isn't a True/False evaluation, it returns an index. A logical test should indicate that. I've actually changed opinions on this matter, so I see your point too.

Comment: BTW, True in VBA maps to -1. It really isn't accurate to say 1,2 or 3 maps to True. It's a *truthy* value, e.g. `debug.print cbool(4) = true` evaluates to True.